# How to build both a library and a test executable in the same Eclipse/CDT project?

Tags: testing, shared-libraries, project-management, executable, eclipse-cdt

I have built a shared library under Eclipse/CDT in C++. To manage my projects tests, I would like to have in the same project the library and an executable for running tests on the library.

How can I do that please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the library itself, I have standard build settings : a `Debug` and a `Release` target, with the `-fPIC` compile option, an artifact type `Shared Library`, extension `so` and prefix `lib`, and the `-share` linker option.

For the test program, I have added in the same project a *main.cpp* file:

```
#ifdef TEST_

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "config.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout << "Test for project utils" << endl;
    return 0;
}

#endif /* TEST_ */
```

I have added a specific `Test` target copied from the `DEBUG` one and adapted for standard executable build settings : suppress the `-fPIC` compile option, add `-D TEST_`, modify the artifact type to `Executable`, supress extension `so` and prefix `lib`, suppress the `-share` option for the linker.

Now, just build Debug, Release, and Test as normal, what can be done independently. The `Test` target could be easily changed for say `Test-Debug` and `Test-Release`, to get a library self-test runned just after installation.